# Wrapping text in R's renderdatatable column heading

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to wrap my columns in entirely - they're currently quite wide because the column name is long. As you can see from the code below, I've tried adding some code under `columndefs` based on things I found on the internet. It doesn't seem to be doing anything though.

Here's my table code in server.R:

```
 output$dc_prod_table = DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(
          merge(dc_merge7(), dc_na(), by.x="dc_name",all.x=TRUE), options= list(page_Length=10, scrollX = T, paging = FALSE, searching = FALSE, 
                                                                                columnDefs = list(list(width = 0.5, targets = list(2,3,4,5)))))
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `autoWidth = FALSE` in your options.
See here https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html